# Portable idiom to determine which many-to-many relation was traversed?

Tags: sql, postgresql, portability

A common model: `lords` have `peons`, and both `lords` and `peons` have `things`. `things` can be owned by one or more `peons` *and* `lords`. To display all `things` owned directly or indirectly by a lord:

```
SELECT lords.id AS lord_id,
       peons.id AS peon_id,
       things.id AS thing_id
  FROM lords
  LEFT JOIN lords_things ON
       lords.id = lords_things.lord_id
  LEFT JOIN peons ON
       lords.id = peons.lord_id
  LEFT JOIN peons_things ON
       peons.id = peons_things.peon_id
  JOIN things ON
       lords_things.thing_id = things.id OR
       peons_things.thing_id = things.id
 WHERE lords.id = 123
```

Now there are two problems:

1. The code will have to look at which of `lord_id` and `peon_id` is non-`NULL` to determine which level the thing is connected to. There are lots of ways to solve this - For example, in Oracle you could say

   ```
   SELECT NVL2(things_lords.id, 'lord', 'peon') as level
   ```

   and in SQL Server you should be able to say

   ```
   SELECT CASE WHEN things_lords.id IS NULL THEN 'peon' ELSE 'lord' END AS level
   ```

   but I don't think either of these are portable (at least to PostgreSQL). A different approach would use a `UNION`:

   ```
   SELECT lords.id AS owner_id,
          'lord' AS level,
          things.id AS thing_id
     FROM lords
     JOIN lords_things ON
          lords.id = lords_things.lord_id
     JOIN things ON
          lords_things.thing_id = things.id
    WHERE lords.id = 123
   UNION
   SELECT peons.id AS owner_id,
          'peon' AS type,
          things.id AS thing_id
     FROM lords
     JOIN peons ON
          lords.id = peons.lord_id
     JOIN peons_things ON
          peons.id = peons_things.peon_id
     JOIN things ON
          peons_things.thing_id = things.id
    WHERE lords.id = 123
   ```

   this is quite ugly since it duplicates almost all the code. Is there a more elegant *portable* solution for this?
2. Some `things` may show up more than once. This is not a problem in my application, but mentioned for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

The`case` statement *is* portable to all database engines (at least all relatively recent ones with the exception of MS Access).  Looking on the web, Postgres supports the case statement at least since version 7.

So, use the case version.

As for the completeness.  You want something like:

```
select things.id,
       (case when max(lords.id) is not null and max(peons.id) is not null then 'BOTH'
             when max(lords.id) is not null then 'LORDS'
             when max(peons.id) is not null then 'PEONS'
             else 'Ooops!'
        end) as wherefrom
. . . 
group by things.id
```

That is, do an aggregation and use the aggregation functions to summarize what you want.